# Cannot get features in the geojson file

Tags: javascript, html, gis, openlayers, geojson

[I shared the result as an image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEfk3.png)

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    
    // Importing OSM map style
    const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        visible: true
    });

   const pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [245, 10, 14, 1]
      }),
      radius: 7,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [245, 10, 14, 1],
        width: 2
            })
        })
    });

    const polygonStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: [247, 66, 10, 1]
        })
      });


    // Calling vector data from the file
    var vectorDataGeoJSON = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: './data/points.geojson' ,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            }),
        //style : [polygonStyle]
        style: [pointStyle]
    });

    var Source = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: './data/points.geojson' ,
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      wrapX: true
      })

    var styleCache = {} ;
    var featureList;
```

**Here, GeoJSON files' features can be shown locally in the console.**

```
    vectorDataGeoJSON.getSource().on('change', function(evt){
            var source = evt.target;
            if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
            var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length;
            var featureList = source.getFeatures();
            console.log("Count after change: " + numFeatures);
            }
            var featureList = this.getFeatures();
            console.log(featureList);
    });
```

**Here, GeoJSON files' features are empty. I want to get them for generating cluster mapping.**

```
    console.log(vectorDataGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatures());
```

I want to get the features in my **vectorDataGeoJSON** variable.

When I use *vectorDataGeoJSON.getSource().on('change', function(evt)*, I can get features in inside of the function, whereas I do not get feature values in the the out of the function.

I searched a lot here, but I did not find solution for this.

Comment: Like most file loads in avascript the geojson file is loaded asynchronously, you must wait for it to load.  There will not be any features available until the change event fires.

Comment: Actually I got features in                          `vectorDataGeoJSON.getSource().on('change', function(evt){
            var source = evt.target;
            if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
            var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length;
            var featureList = source.getFeatures();
            console.log("Count after change: " + numFeatures);
            }
            var featureList = this.getFeatures();
            console.log(featureList);
    });`                         .But when I call in the out of it, it respond as "undefined"

Comment: Yes, because the code inside function(evt){...} only runs after the source has changed.  The code outside it runs immediately, before the data has loaded.  It is like putting the code inside a setTimeout function.

Comment: @Mike, what would you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Any code which needs the features array needs to go inside the on change callback.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike . I defined my other functions in `function(evt){...}`. And it works.